# TeX fonts similar to Perpetua?

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a free/lite font, preferably with maths support, that resembles Eric Gill’s Perpetua. Does one exist?

Comment: Is TeX Gyre Pagella close enough? https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/tex-gyre-pagella

Comment: I doubt you’ll find a free version. (Unfortunately, it’s only too easy to find pirated fonts with broken kerning and other such flaws.) [Luc Devroye](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-26302.html) notes Bitstream’s relatively inexpensive version, Lapidary 333, but if you examine it, you’ll find this to be a case of ‘you get what you pay for.’

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perpetua directly in text with `fontspec`, and in math mode with `unicode-math` (in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX), `mathastext` (in any engine) or `mathspec` (XeLaTeX only).  Note that the digital Pro from Monotype does not include any Greek letters but π, even though the metal typeface did.

The code to use Perpetua with `unicode-math` might look something like:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Perpetua}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{Perpetua}[range=up/{Latin,latin,digits}]
\setmathfont{Perpetua Italic}[range=it/{Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Perpetua Bold}[range=bfup/{Latin,latin,digits}]
\setmathfont{Perpetua Bold Italic}[range=bfit/{Latin,latin}]
```

Keep in mind that there are several versions of Perpetua.  The one bundled with MS Office is stripped down, and the full features, such as ligatures and kerning, are (as far as I know) only in the Pro version sold by Monotype.

There is in fact a `perpetua.sty` on CTAN, but it [requires the Type 1 fonts distributed with Corel software](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/corelpak) back in the mid-’90s. A quarter-century ago, this was a cheaper option for many people than buying fonts from Adobe.  The Corel Pak distributes TeX font metrics (`.tfm` files) and mappings for T1 and OT1 (`.fd` files), but not the fonts themselves.  This might still work for you, if you happen to have a version of Corel Draw from last century, but it should be considered obsolete today.

If you convert the OpenType font to a Type 1 TeX font and install it under the family name `bpp`, it is possible that the stylesheet from that package might work for you in PDFTeX.  However, I recommend using modern fonts in LuaTeX when you can and PDFTeX when you have to.

Comment: Very nice....I have seen that exist also the `\usepackage{Perpetua}`. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Good catch! I added a paragraph about it.

Comment: LoL :-) http://c.caignaert.free.fr/Install-ttf-Font.pdf but I have not able to use it :-(.

Comment: @Sebastiano I believe the version that ships with MS Office is stripped-down, and the Pro version you can buy from Monotype has more advanced features, such as ligatures and kerning.

Answer (score 0):

My answer it is very short but I hope that you can take a benefit for this. I have seen into this [file](http://c.caignaert.free.fr/Install-ttf-Font.pdf) that exist Perpetua font used with `LaTeX`. Here there is also the list of the font with math support used with `pdfLaTeX`.

I will use this `BaskervilleF` or [ScholaX](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/scholax/):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{baskervillef}
\usepackage[baskerville,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.

\[\int \frac{(2-t)dt}{(5+3t)(1+t^2)}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]